# HERE API request returns view instead of JSON

Tags: api, response, here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm trying to use the [Places (Search) API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/quick-start-find-text-string.html) (or [any HERE API](https://developer.here.com/documentation) for that matter) for the first time. I tried the example in [this page](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/request-constructing.html) and got this page as a response:

https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/browse?app_id=YOUR-APP-ID&app_code=YOUR-APP-CODE&in=52.521,13.3807;r=2000&cat=petrol-station&pretty
 [image: this view]

I don't know what I'm missing here but, I expected to get a plain JSON/XML response (orange rectangle), like this example of the [Routing (Isoline) API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/request-a-simple-route.html) which outputs this to the browser:

https://isoline.route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&jsonAttributes=1&rangetype=time&start=34.603565,-98.3959&app_id=YOUR-APP-ID&app_code=YOUR-APP-CODE&range=1800

[image]

this way I could consume the service using the JSON/XML output.

I already tried both examples above in my Spring (JAVA) app and the second one works as expected, while the first one throws error (as expected).

HERE API newbie here, help appreciated.

PS: this project app of mine is just about finding nearby POIs (e.g: gyms, coffee shops, pharmacies, cinemas, etc). So, any suggestions on what API is best to go with for this, also very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the HERE api but from having a quick look it seems they generate your results depending on the `Accept` header in your http request.

By default my chrome sends this accept header:

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
```

If I use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to send the request without any Accept header or `Accept: application/json` it returns the json results.

[image: Accept-application-json]

If I add an `Accept: text/html` header to the request in Postman it sends me the PlayPen in html.

[image: Accept-text-html]

You can also see in their documentation that they use the appropriate `Accept: application/json`

[image]

I suggest you use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test and play with the API's.

Comment: yep, they killed me with *Defaults to `application/json`*. Didn't realize the browser would get in the way; Chrome, FF, Edge and IExplorer all send the html page unless `Accept=application/json` is added to the url